# *ngIf with function onClick

Tags: angular

I want to got clicked function depending on user role.
I tried something like this

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" *ngIf="currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR'?(click)=function_one():(click)=function_two()"
```

But this doesn't works.
Error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression
```

this:  `*ngIf="currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR'`

works fine but I can't use (click) inside "".
When I did just function_one():function_two() it works but I want to got this function onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a design issue

Try this instead:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

Component:

```
onClick(){
 currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR' ? function1() : function2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need change to this following code and remove `*ngIf` condition

```
<button class="btn btn-success (click)="function_click()" />
function_click(){

if(this.currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR') {

this.function_one();
}else{
this.function_two();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. There are several alternatives, for example

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" *ngIf="currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR'" (click)="function_one()">...</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" *ngIf="currentRole !== 'ROLE_MODERATOR'" (click)="function_two()">...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`*ngIf` directive only designed to accept `true` or `false` whether to add the element to the DOM or not.
If you want to activate different methods (/functions) based on a condition - use it as the following:

```js
<button
   class="btn btn-success btn-block"
   (click)="currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR'? function_one() : function_two()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one way to do this. You have to do the if-else logic inside the (click).

Here is an example:

```
(click)="currentRole === 'ROLE_MODERATOR' ? function_one() : function_two()"
```

If condition is true it will call function_one() otherwise function_two().
Hope this helps you.